# AngularJS Directives: how to compile html after promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which calls another directive passing some values as object. My problem is that the template gets compiled before the promise getting the data is satisfied.

The directive:

```
var directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);
    directives.directive('mydirective', function (myService, $http, $compile) {
        var templateUrl = "/some/file.html";
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            scope: {
                entry: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var entry = scope.entry;
                var template = {
                    //** some empty key - value pairs **//
                };


                $http.get(templateUrl).then(function (response) {
                    element.html(response);

                    myService(entry.id, function (err, res) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;

                       //** code to fill the template object **//

                        scope.seqplot = template;
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

The template (the seqplot directive can be accessed [here](https://github.com/tdido/angular-seqplot)):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            Some header
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in seqplot.k2 track by $index">
            {{$index}}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{seqplot.k1[$index]}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <seqplot data-bar-width="666" 
                         data-region-data="seqplot.k3" 
                         data-regions='seqplot.k2[$index]' 
                         data-seq="{{seqplot.k4}}" 
                         data-gradient="true"></seqplot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The partial where I call the directive:

```
<div>   
    <h1 class="page-header">{{entry.name| uppercase}} <small> - {{entry.uniprot_id| uppercase}}</small> </h1>
    <div mydirective data-entry="entry"></div>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
var ctrlEntry = controllers.controller('ctrlEntry', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {

    var getEntry = function (obj_arr, id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj_arr.length; i++) {
            var curr = obj_arr[i];
            if (curr.id === id) {
                return curr;
            }
        }
    };

    var data = $rootScope.data;

    var path = $location.path().split('/');
    var entry_id = path[path.length - 1];
    $scope.entry = getEntry(data, entry_id);
});
```

The problem is the the mydirective's scope.seqplot object is passed to the seqplot directive before myService callback get executed. Therefore I suspect I need some way to recompile the html template right after the service callback get executed or make the directive wait to compile the template until the service callback gets fully executed. Ideas? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization logic doesn't belong to directive link function. Best case would be to use router (ngRoute / ui-router) which provide you with `resolve` property where everything is initialized before entering UI so all data is ready before compiling directives.